# update MySQL table does not work with jquery

Tags: mysql, jqgrid

**SOLVED**
I have duplicated element ID on the page.

My `update` table does not work. I have dialog form that selects the data from jqGrid row,
and this is the code.

```
    function editDialog() {
        //cek baris terpilih
        var selr = jQuery('#list1').jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
        if(!selr){
            alert("Harap pilih baris yang ingin di edit")
        return}
        var namapelanggan = jQuery('#list1').jqGrid('getCell', selr, 'namapelanggan');
        var alamatpelanggan = jQuery('#list1').jqGrid('getCell', selr, 'alamat');
        var telppelanggan = jQuery('#list1').jqGrid('getCell', selr, 'telepon');
    $("input#namapelanggan").val(namapelanggan);
    $("input#alamatpelanggan").val(alamatpelanggan);
    $("input#telppelanggan").val(telppelanggan);
    $( "#editDialog" ).dialog("open");
}
```

and below is the jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $dialog = $("#editDialog")
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            position: 'center',
            hide: 'explode',
            modal: true,
            width: 'auto',
            height: 'auto',
            closeOnEscape: true,
            buttons: [{ text: "Simpan", click: function (){
                var
                xnama = $("input#namapelanggan").val();
                xalamat = $("input#alamatpelanggan").val();
                xtelp = $("input#telppelanggan").val();
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/sis/modul/mod_pelanggan/upelanggan.php",
            data: {"nama":xnama,
            "alamat":xalamat,
            "telp":xtelp,
            success: function(result){
            jQuery("#list1").trigger("reloadGrid");
            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert('Terjadi kesalahan, Error Kode: ' + xhr.status);}
                            }
            );
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }},
        { text: "Batal", click: function () { $(this).dialog("close"); } }]
    });
});
```

here is the `upelanggan.php` for query update the table.

```
<?PHP
include "../../../config/koneksi.php";
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { //halaman ini harus dipanggil melalui post
      $nama = $_POST["nama"];
      $alamat = $_POST["alamat"];
      $telp = $_POST["telp"];
      $sql="UPDATE tpelanggan SET namapelanggan='".$nama."' ,alamat='".$alamat."',telepon='".$telp."' WHERE idpelanggan=1 ";
      $q = mysql_query($sql);
}
?>
```

User clicks edit from selected row then the dialog form is opened. User changes the input value id namapelanggan and clicks the button 'Simpan' to save changed. But it doesn't work, the table not updated.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work: is there an error, or is it just that the database isn't updated?

Comment: the table isn't updated, there is no error.

Comment: Can you post the value of `$sql` please: this would help determine whether the problem is with your SQL, or perhaps earlier in the PHP.

Comment: "*But it doesn't work*" is not an acceptable error description.

Answer (score 0):

In first check that POST request is running.

You can make it by FireBug on tab "Console" or "Net"

Also you can check it by access log on your web server.

Also in your code I found errors in $.ajax run:

1. Strange `"nopolisi":xnopolisi` because varaible xnopolisi not defined.
2. Not exists closed brackes `}` for data field.

Check Javascript console for errors and fix it.

Comment: sory for the variable nopolisi it's not used. look for my update query.

Comment: yes, it not used, but it not defined and you can have Javascript error and ajax request just don't send to PHP script. And it nod send because you have other error in your script

Comment: for clear, i copy some of the code from my original code and post here. and I suppose to copy it end the "telp":xtelp, not including "nopolisi:xnopolisi. There is no Javascript error, i checked the log of firebug from the console and look for the POST data. the POST data is send the data from my selected grid row, so the changed data is not sending and the table not updated.

Comment: Strange. Your code is not very correct. But if in POST all fields is filled as need, then just check mysql_query status: `echo mysql_error()`. And view output in firebug console

Comment: My code is correct, firebug not showing error. the query is updating old data not edited data. If I can post an images it would be more clear.